# XCode project corruption

Tags: xcode

I've been working on an iOS project in XCode for a while now (XCode 4.4.1). This morning, I started up XCode (first time fresh for a while) and it started downloading an update. Once this was done, I noticed that most of my project was gone. All of my original files had been removed from the project. I checked the filesystem and they were still there.

I restored the project folder from Timemachine but the project was really confused and throught it was a MacOS project. So I created a new project and just copied my files into it.

That kinda of worked but now when my app runs it always runs in portrait mode even though I've set the project options to only run in landscape mode.  In landscape mode, the text (and buttons and such) are all 90 degrees off. When I rotate the simulator the app does not respond.

I've set the storyboards to all run in both inferred and landscape orientation but neither worked.

Am I missing a project setting that will let my app work again?

Has anyone else suffered a project corruption like this?

Answer (score 0):

I saw something like this when I migrated to iOS 6.  I just bit the bullet and manually changed my MainWindow/RootViewController setup into a MainStoryboard.  It worked out pretty well.  Make sure you've disabled [devil autolayout](http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/) too.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I'm dumb.

The project was corrected so I rebuilt it. Being stupid, I changed the name of a couple of files (the view controllers) but forgot to update the storyboards. That's what happened when things go bung at 5AM.